# How to create back to back histogram using ggplot2 in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I have a `df` called `TP_FP` and would like to create a back to back (mirrored) histogram based on Group column using ggplot2.

```
 `TP_FP`
           Value        Group        
            <dbl>       <chr>         
         1 -0.00540   False positive
         2  0.331     True positive
         3 -1.11      False positive
         4  1.4365    False positive
         5 -0.586     True positive
         6  1.26      True positive
         7  0.5463    False positive
         8  3.245     False positive
         9 -0.950     False positive
        10 10.4354    True positive
```

I have tried the following:

```
ggplot(TP_FP, aes(x=x)) +
      geom_histogram(aes(x=Value, y = -..density.., fill= Group == "False positive"),col="black", binwidth = 0.1) +
      geom_histogram( aes(x=Value,y = ..density.., fill= Group =="True positive"),col="black", binwidth = 0.1) +
      labs(x="R Ratio", y="Number of proteins") +
      theme_bw() + theme(legend.position="right")
```

I would expect to get a merged histogram like the one at the bottom.

[image: This is what I've got.]

[image: This is what I would expect]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this?

```
library(tidyverse)
TP_FP <- tribble(~Value, ~Group,        
                -0.00540, "False positive",
                0.331, "True positive",
                -1.11, "False positive",
                1.4365, "False positive",
                -0.586, "True positive",
                1.26, "True positive",
                0.5463, "False positive",
                3.245, "False positive",
                -0.950, "False positive",
                10.4354, "True positive")

ggplot() +
  geom_histogram(data = TP_FP %>% filter(Group == "False positive"),
                 aes(y = -(..density..), x = Value, fill = Group),
                 col = "black", binwidth = 0.1) +
  geom_histogram(data = TP_FP %>% filter(Group == "True positive"),
                 aes(y = ..density.., x = Value, fill = Group),
                 col = "black", binwidth = 0.1) +
  labs(x = "R Ratio", y = "Number of proteins") +
  theme_bw() + theme(legend.position = "right")
```

[image: example.png]